# Terminal Command to suspend a package download on XLTerminal

Tags: cmdline.txt

Hi the Wolfphram package im trying to install has been installing for over an hour. It is at 5%.  I want to stop it. All the searches come up with ways to clear the terminal when you finish. Is there such a command to stop end and then erase the package?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried ^C - if that doesn't work ^D

Comment: I tried ^C it did nork. ^D actually worked..Thanks fort the quick and correct response

Comment: This is notorious for slow downloads. You can stop it updating with `sudo apt-mark hold wolfram-engine`.

Comment: Great to know..is the package one that will be missed if i uninstall it?

Comment: There is no need to uninstall, although it is large, but unless you need the space, leave it and try. If you have never used it you won't miss it.

Answer (score 0):

Close the terminal itself , open it again and type this command :

```
sudo apt-get purge -y wolfram-engine
```

and

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

wolfram installation will be successfully cancelled .